# How to find a group using musonza/groups package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to use musonza/groups so i can build a group system on my app 
any idea how can i find a group so I can use request function that we have in the package?
I tryed this but it's not working code:

```
use Groups;
use Auth;
public function makerequest($id){

        $userId=Auth::User()->id;


        $group->request($userId);

        return redirect()->back()->withMessage('request done!');


    }
```

I get Undefined variable: group error because I don't know what is the function to find my group using the facade 
nb: I get $id from the form

Answer (score 0):

To find the group use 
group($groupId)